# d3.js gives NAN in path.line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Getting the following error in chrome, looks like path.line is barfing on my json data I am not sure why, it is valid json.
Thanks for any help in advance!

my code: data and error are after the code. Thanks !

```
   <script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
//d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
//    data.forEach(function(d) {
//        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
//        d.close = +d.close;
//    });
// Get the data
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      Date d.date = inputFormat.parse(d.SAMPLETIME);
      //  d.date = Date.parse(d.SAMPLETIME);
        d.close = parseFloat(d.SAMPLEVALUE);
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

});
```

the Error ia m getting from the js console is (shortened for brevity)

```
<path class="line" d="MNaN,210LNaN,210LNaN,210LNaN,210LNaN,210LNaN,210LNaN,210LNaN,210LNaN,210"></path>
```

my json data file looks like this I am using SAMPLETIME and SAMPLEVALUE

```
[
  {
    "R_TABLE": "RN_QOS_DATA_0001",
    "TABLE_ID": "7947",
    "ROBOT": "xx",
    "SOURCE": "xx.xx.xx.net",
    "QOS": "QOS_PROC_QUEUE_LEN",
    "SAMPLETIME": "18-OCT-15 06.13.28.000000 PM",
    "SAMPLEVALUE": ".04"
  },
  {
    "R_TABLE": "RN_QOS_DATA_0001",
    "TABLE_ID": "7947",
    "ROBOT": "xx",
    "SOURCE": "xx.xx.xx.net",
    "QOS": "QOS_PROC_QUEUE_LEN",
    "SAMPLETIME": "18-OCT-15 06.23.28.000000 PM",
    "SAMPLEVALUE": ".01"
  },
  {
    "R_TABLE": "RN_QOS_DATA_0001",
    "TABLE_ID": "7947",
    "ROBOT": "xx",
    "SOURCE": "xx.xx.xx.net",
    "QOS": "QOS_PROC_QUEUE_LEN",
    "SAMPLETIME": "18-OCT-15 06.33.28.000000 PM",
    "SAMPLEVALUE": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you using any error handling or logging to make sure data.json loads properly, like checking for what is in 'error' before using 'data'?  Also a logging opportunity exists within your data.forEach function.

Comment: There is no `SimpleDateFormat` in JavaScript, that's Java... For this reason your dates won't get parsed, which will eventually result in `NaN`s for your x values in the path's `d` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date in your data is not a valid date.

You can see this in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsf9o9w6/2/)

You could split this date first to remove the time like so:

```
var date = '18-OCT-15 06.23.28.000000 PM'

//split the string by the space and take the first part
 date.split(' ')[0];

// create new date object
 var new_date = new Date(date)
```

Comment: I am new to javascript but writing perl forever, i will have to see if javascript has default variables or not.. I assigned the split  to a new var and used that var in the New Date(). Thanks for the help !

Comment: so that date works, but but my data date/time based so just having a date with a lot of data points looks sort a wonky. I have not been able to figure out how to get a date time that is usable with d3.js.. womp womp

Comment: It's because of the dots, think if you replace them with colons it should work!